# Is there any command like "webbrowser" in python to open installed computer applications in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

Like the command 'webbrowser' opens my browser to fetch the site, is there any command to open an application in python.
For example, if i want to open visual studio code, how can I open it using python. What is the command used.

Comment: Python has functions, not commands. If you want to run a command, look into `subprocess.run()` and friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
Use os.system command to do the process.

Example:

```
elif 'open google chrome' in query:
        print("opening google chrome....")
        speak("opening google chrome....")
        command = "google-chrome"       #It's so easy!!!
        os.system(command)
```